# Kotlin compile error: Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

¿Cómo se gestionan los genéricos en Kotlin?:

Tengo una interfice y su correspondiente implementación generados con IntelliJ a partir de código java.
La interfice que me ha generado es:

```
package com.talleres.paco.mako.commons.repository

import com.talleres.paco.mako.commons.dto.Page

/**
 * Plantilla genérica para los DAO. Para no repetir los DAO's utilizamos
 * generics de java. Ya que todas los DAO's a priori hacen las mismas
 * operaciones.

 * @param T Clase de los objetos a persistir/manipular en BD.
 * *
 * @param PK Tipo de la primary key.
 * *
 * @param C Criteria para montar la cláusula where de las queries.
 * *
 * @param Q Tipo Query para un los objetos clase T.
 * *
 * *
 * @author José-Alberto Gilberte León ().
 */
interface IRepository<T, PK, C, Q> {

    /**
     * Devuelve todos los objetos de tipo T que cumplan los criterios y el filtro si los tienen

     * @param namedQuery Nombre de la query customizada que se desea ejecutar.
     * *
     * @param criteria Dto con criterios de busqueda
     * *
     * @return List con todos los objetos de tipo T que cumplen los criterios
     */
    fun findByCriteria(namedQuery: String, criteria: C): List<T>

    /**
     * Devuelve todas los objetos de tipo T que cumplan los criterios y el filtro si los tienen
     * en un objeto Page.

     * @param namedQuery Query customizada que se desea ejecutar.
     * *
     * @param rowCountQuery Query de oonteo del número total de elementos
     * *
     * @param criteria Dto con criterios de búsqueda
     * *
     * @return Page con todas las entidades tipo T y contadores que cumplen el criterio.
     */
    fun findPageByCriteria(namedQuery: String, rowCountQuery: String, criteria: C): Page<T>

    /**
     * Devuelve todos los objetos de tipo T que cumplan los criterios y el filtro si los tienen

     * @param criteria Dto con criterios de busqueda
     * *
     * @return List con todos los objetos de tipo T que cumplen los criterios
     */
    fun findByCriteria(criteria: C): List<T>

    /**
     * Devuelve todas los objetos de tipo T que cumplan los criterios y el filtro si los tienen
     * en un objeto Page.

     * @param criteria Dto con criterios de búsqueda
     * *
     * @return Page con todas las entidades tipo T y contadores que cumplen el criterio.
     */
    fun findPageByCriteria(criteria: C): Page<T>

    /**
     * Obtiene un objeto T de la base de datos

     * @param id El identificador de la entidad T
     * *
     * @return La entidad T
     */
    fun findById(id: PK): T

    /**
     * Inserta un objeto T

     * @param  dto Un dto de la entidad T
     * *
     * @return La entidad T.
     */
    fun insert(dto: T): T

    /**
     * Actualiza un objeto T

     * @param dto Un dto de la entidad T
     * *
     * @return La entidad T.
     */
    fun update(dto: T): T

    /**
     * Elimina un objeto T

     * @param id del dto de tipo T
     * *
     * @return Número de filas borradas
     */
    fun delete(id: PK): Int

    /**
     * Elimina n objetos T por Criteria.

     * @param Criteria para borrar
     * *
     * @return Número de filas borradas
     */
    fun deleteByCriteria(criteria: C): Int
}
```

Y la implementación:

```
package com.talleres.paco.mako.commons.repository.impl

import java.io.Serializable
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
import java.util.*

import org.slf4j.*
import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport

import com.talleres.paco.mako.commons.repository.IRepository
import com.talleres.paco.mako.commons.dto.Page
import com.talleres.paco.mako.commons.dto.criteria.BaseCriteria
import com.talleres.paco.mako.commons.dto.model.SqlParametrizable
import com.talleres.paco.mako.commons.jdbc.Query

/**
 * Plantilla genérica para los DAO. Para no repetir los DAO's utilizamos
 * generics de java. Ya que todas los DAO's a priori hacen las mismas
 * operaciones.

 * @param T - Clase de los objetos a persistir/manipular en BD.
 * *
 * @param PK - Tipo básico de la surrogate key
 * *
 * @param R - RowMapper mapeador de filas sql a objeto de tipo T
 * *
 * @param C - Criteria para montar la cláusula where de las queries.
 * *
 * @param Q - Query para montar el sql de las queries.
 * *
 * *
 * @author José-Alberto Gilberte León ().
 */
class Repository<T : SqlParametrizable<java.lang.String>, PK : Serializable, R : RowMapper<T>, C : BaseCriteria, Q : Query<C>> : JdbcDaoSupport(), IRepository<T, PK, C, Q> {
    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)
    private var rowMapperClass: Class<R>? = null
    private var queryClass: Class<Q>? = null
    var namedParameterJdbcOperations: NamedParameterJdbcOperations? = null
    private val DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 10
    private val MINIMUN_PAGE_SIZE = 1
    private val MINIMUN_PAGE_NUMBER = 1
    private val SQL_WORD_LIMIT = " LIMIT "
    private val SQL_WORD_OFFSET = " OFFSET "

    private fun initializeRepository() {
        var genericClass: Class<*> = javaClass
        while (Repository<*, *, *, *, *>::class.java.simpleName != genericClass.superclass.simpleName) {
            if (genericClass.genericSuperclass is ParameterizedType)
                break
            genericClass = genericClass.superclass
        }
        if (genericClass.genericSuperclass is ParameterizedType) {
            val parameterizedType = genericClass.genericSuperclass as ParameterizedType
            rowMapperClass = parameterizedType.actualTypeArguments[2] as Class<R>
            queryClass = parameterizedType.actualTypeArguments[4] as Class<Q>
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor vacío
     */
    init {
        initializeRepository()
    }

    /**
     * Muestra en las trazas de log los parámetros de la query.

     * @param mapSqlParameterSource Parámetros de la consulta.
     */
    private fun debugSqlParameters(mapSqlParameterSource: MapSqlParameterSource) {
        if (isNotEmptyMapSqlParameterSource(mapSqlParameterSource)) {
            var key: String? = null
            var value: Any? = null
            for ((key1, value1) in mapSqlParameterSource.values) {
                key = key1
                value = value1
                log.debug(key + ": " + value)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun isNotEmptyMapSqlParameterSource(mapSqlParameterSource: MapSqlParameterSource?): Boolean {
        if (mapSqlParameterSource != null
                && mapSqlParameterSource.values != null
                && mapSqlParameterSource.values.entries != null) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve todos los objetos de tipo T que cumplan los criterios y el filtro si los tienen.

     * @param criteria Dto con criterios de busqueda
     * *
     * @return List con todos los objetos de tipo T que cumplen los criterios
     * *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun findByCriteria(criteria: C): List<T> {
        return findByCriteria(queryClass!!.newInstance().toSQLFetchRows(criteria), criteria)
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve todos los objetos de tipo T que cumplan los criterios y el filtro si los tienen.

     * @param namedQuery Query customizada que se desea ejecutar.
     * *
     * @param criteria Dto con criterios de busqueda
     * *
     * @return List con todos los objetos de tipo T que cumplen los criterios
     * *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun findByCriteria(namedQuery: String, criteria: C): List<T> {
        return namedParameterJdbcOperations!!.query(namedQuery, criteria.mapSQLParameterSource, rowMapperClass!!.newInstance())
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve todas los objetos de tipo T que cumplan los criterios y el filtro si los tienen
     * en un objeto Page.

     * @param criteria - Dto con criterios de búsqueda
     * *
     * @return Page con todas las entidades tipo T y contadores que cumplen el criterio.
     * *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun findPageByCriteria(criteria: C): Page<T> {
        if (criteria.pageSize < MINIMUN_PAGE_SIZE)
            criteria.pageSize = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE
        if (criteria.actualPage < MINIMUN_PAGE_NUMBER)
            criteria.actualPage = MINIMUN_PAGE_NUMBER
        else if (criteria.totalPages > 0 && criteria.actualPage > criteria.totalPages)
            criteria.actualPage = criteria.totalPages
        val query = queryClass!!.newInstance()
        return findPageByCriteria(query.toSQLFetchRows(criteria), query.toSQLRowCount(criteria), criteria)
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve todas los objetos de tipo T que cumplan los criterios y el filtro si los tienen
     * en un objeto Page.

     * @param namedQuery Query customizada que se desea ejecutar.
     * *
     * @param rowCountQuery Query para contar el número total de filas.
     * *
     * @param criteria - Dto con criterios de búsqueda
     * *
     * @return Page con todas las entidades tipo T y contadores que cumplen el criterio.
     * *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun findPageByCriteria(namedQuery: String, rowCountQuery: String, criteria: C): Page<T> {
        val sqlFetchRows = addLimitAndOffset(namedQuery, criteria)
        val rowMapper = rowMapperClass!!.newInstance()
        val res = namedParameterJdbcOperations!!.query(sqlFetchRows, criteria.mapSQLParameterSource, rowMapper)
        val totalRows = namedParameterJdbcOperations!!.queryForObject(rowCountQuery, criteria.mapSQLParameterSource, Int::class.java)
        criteria.totalPages = totalRows
        val resultPage = Page<T>()
        resultPage.content = res
        return calculateCountersPage(resultPage, criteria, totalRows)
    }

    private fun addLimitAndOffset(query: String, criteria: C?): String {
        val queryLimited = StringBuilder(query)
        queryLimited.append(SQL_WORD_LIMIT)
        queryLimited.append(criteria!!.pageSize)
        queryLimited.append(SQL_WORD_OFFSET)
        var offset = 0
        if (criteria != null && criteria.actualPage > MINIMUN_PAGE_NUMBER)
            offset = (criteria.actualPage - 1) * criteria.pageSize
        return queryLimited.append(offset).toString()
    }

    private fun calculateCountersPage(page: Page<T>, criteria: C?, totalRows: Int): Page<T> {
        page.totalElements = totalRows.toLong()
        if (totalRows == 0)
            page.totalPages = 0
        else if (criteria != null && criteria.pageSize != 0)
            page.totalPages = Math.ceil((totalRows / criteria.pageSize).toDouble()).toInt()

        if (page.content != null && page.content.size > 0)
            page.size = page.content.size
        else
            page.size = 0
        page.number = criteria!!.actualPage
        return page
    }

    /**
     * Obtiene un objeto T de la base de datos

     * @param id - El identificador de la entidad T
     * *
     * @return La entidad T
     */
    override fun findById(id: PK): T {
        val sql = queryClass!!.newInstance().toSQLFindById()
        val keyNamePrimary = queryClass!!.newInstance().namePrimaryKey
        val parameters = HashMap<String, Any>()
        parameters.put(keyNamePrimary, id)
        val rowMapper = rowMapperClass!!.newInstance()
        var dto: T? = null
        try {
            dto = namedParameterJdbcOperations!!.queryForObject(sql, parameters, rowMapper)
        } catch (e: EmptyResultDataAccessException) {
        }

        return dto
    }

    /**
     * Inserta un objeto T

     * @param dto - Un dto de la entidad T
     * *
     * @return La entidad T.
     */
    override fun insert(dto: T): T {
        namedParameterJdbcOperations!!.update(queryClass!!.newInstance().toSQLInsert(), dto.toMapSqlParameterSource())
        return dto
    }

    /**
     * Actualiza un objeto T

     * @param dto - Un dto de la entidad T
     * *
     * @return La entidad T.
     */
    override fun update(dto: T): T {
        val parameters = dto.toMapSqlParameterSource()
        val rows = namedParameterJdbcOperations!!.update(queryClass!!.newInstance().toSQLUpdate(), parameters)
        if (rows != 0)
            dto.version = dto.version!! + 1
        return dto
    }

    /**
     * Elimina un objeto T

     * @param id - Identificador del dto de tipo T
     * *
     * @return Número de filas borradas
     */
    override fun delete(id: PK): Int {
        val parameters = HashMap<String, Any>()
        parameters.put("ID", id)
        return namedParameterJdbcOperations!!.update(queryClass!!.newInstance().toSQLDeleteById(), parameters)
    }

    /**
     * Elimina n objetos T por Criteria.

     * @param Criteria para borrar
     * *
     * @return Número de filas borradas
     */
    override fun deleteByCriteria(criteria: C): Int {
        return namedParameterJdbcOperations!!.update(queryClass!!.newInstance().toSQLDelete(criteria), criteria.mapSQLParameterSource.values)
    }
}
```

El problema es que lo generado por IntelliJ no compila en el siguiente método en Kotlin:

```
class Repository<T : SqlParametrizable<java.lang.String>, PK : Serializable, R : RowMapper<T>, C : BaseCriteria, Q : Query<C>> : JdbcDaoSupport(), IRepository<T, PK, C, Q> {


private fun initializeRepository() {
    var genericClass: Class<*> = javaClass
    while (Repository<*, *, *, *, *>::class.java.simpleName != genericClass.superclass.simpleName) {
        if (genericClass.genericSuperclass is ParameterizedType)
            break
        genericClass = genericClass.superclass
    }
    if (genericClass.genericSuperclass is ParameterizedType) {
        val parameterizedType = genericClass.genericSuperclass as ParameterizedType
        rowMapperClass = parameterizedType.actualTypeArguments[2] as Class<R>
        queryClass = parameterizedType.actualTypeArguments[4] as Class<Q>
    }
}
```

Me da el siguiente error en la línea:
while (Repository<*, *, *, *, *>::class.java.simpleName != genericClass.superclass.simpleName) {
Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal

Su equivalente en Java que si compila es:

```
public class Repository<T extends SqlParametrizable<java.lang.String>, PK extends Serializable, R extends RowMapper<T>, C extends BaseCriteria, Q extends Query<C>> 
    extends JdbcDaoSupport 
    implements IRepository<T, PK, C, Q> {


private void initializeRepository() {
    Class<?> genericClass = getClass();
    while (!Repository.class.getSimpleName().equals(genericClass.getSuperclass().getSimpleName())) {
        if (genericClass.getGenericSuperclass() instanceof ParameterizedType)
            break;
        genericClass = genericClass.getSuperclass();
    }
    if (genericClass.getGenericSuperclass() instanceof ParameterizedType) {
        ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) genericClass.getGenericSuperclass();
        rowMapperClass = (Class<R>) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[2];
        queryClass = (Class<Q>) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[4];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parece que se arregla poniendo lo siguiente:

```
private fun initializeRepository() {
    var genericClass: Class<*> = javaClass
    while (Repository::class.java.simpleName != genericClass.superclass.simpleName) {
        if (genericClass.genericSuperclass is ParameterizedType)
            break
        genericClass = genericClass.superclass
    }
    if (genericClass.genericSuperclass is ParameterizedType) {
        val parameterizedType = genericClass.genericSuperclass as ParameterizedType
        rowMapperClass = parameterizedType.actualTypeArguments[2] as Class<R>
        queryClass = parameterizedType.actualTypeArguments[4] as Class<Q>
    }
}
```

Comment: Esta respuesta pretendia ser una explicacion o la encontraste tras hacer la pregunta?

Comment: @lois6b viendo los tiempos de publicación de cada uno, me parece que mientras tipeaba o adaptaba el código para la pregunta, ya iba comprendiendo mejor la situación y descubrió una solución.

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ tiene pinta. Con esto queria llegar a dos posibles conclusiones: 1) si se dio cuenta después, se tiene que emplear mas tiempo buscando una respuesta. 2) si pretendia ser autorespuesta, entoces ha de seguir un formato de respuesta segun [answer] y explicar mejor en qué fallaba la pregunta y como la respuesta puede dar solución. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b a mí me ha pasado algunas veces, solo que terminaba borrando la pregunta porque ya tenía la respuesta y era un caso puntual mío. Además, publicar la pregunta no significa que no seguiré buscando una solución. No creo que esto tenga la pinta de ser una auto respuesta, es un caso muy puntual, se puede inferir por el texto de la pregunta (o al menos eso quisiera creer)

Comment: Señores, creo que Op abandono la pregunta.. no se si merece quedar abierta. OP ni siquiera hizo el tour.. y no se entiende su respuesta.